# Can I prevent Python input() printing the keypresses?

Tags: python

So I was making a project and when I put:

```
print("Press 1 to advance.")
import time
for _ in range(3):
    user_input = input("1")
```

It automatically printed a 1, however, I didn't want that to happen. I wanted it to detect if you press "1" it moves on, and, well, it does that. But again, it also automatically prints it. Can someone help?

Comment: Default Python is designed to work as a console application. That means, generally speaking, it takes input as a stream of text and produces output as a stream of text, rather than detecting individual keystrokes. If you need control over individual keystrokes, you'll need a terminal library like ncurses or a GUI library like tkinter.

Comment: What was the point of asking the user to press 1?  They have to hit Enter anyway to complete the `input()`, and with your current code it doesn't actually matter what they type before that, so the prompt might as well just be "Press Enter to advance".

Comment: `I wanted it to detect if you press "1" it moves on` what "does it do" if I press 'n' or nothing at all? And, getting bored, <enter>?

Answer (score 1):

That happened because you asked python to print it.

Any statement which is written in `input()` is a display statement

So to solve your issue just remove `"1"` from input function

your code would be

```
print("Press 1 to advance.")
import time
for _ in range(3):
    user_input=input()
```

to check user entered 1 or not you can use an if statement as

```
print("Press 1 to advance.")
import time
for _ in range(3):
    user_input=input()
    if user_input != "1":
        break
```